# Django - ./manage.py defaults to python 2.x

Tags: django, python-3.x, manage.py

So I've: `chmod +x manage.py`so I can just `./manage.py` when needed, but it defaults to python 2.7, but I want it to use python 3.4 I also have installed. I know I could just use `python3 manage.py`but I want to know if there's a way to use the shortcut without calling the default python.

I'm on Ubuntu, not in a virtual environment, and don't want to make py3 the default as I know py2 is required by some core operations in the system, so I'd appreciate a localized solution.

Thanks!

**EDIT**: Days after this question I started to experience problems at the system level due to messing around with the default python 2 of the system and python 3, and solved the conflict issues by using a virtualenv. So if you're in my same position, just use a virtualenv(even if you don't like the concept, like me) it saves you future headaches.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to fix it is to change the first line in your `./manage.py` to

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
```

However it is much better to use `virtualenv` to manage all your python environments.

Comment: I read that changing the hashbang could cause problems in production as it's a os-dependent.

https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/19238

Comment: You must be kidding. Why ask a question if you already googled the answer?

Comment: I wanted to make sure there was no other way. And apparently I'll have to change the hashbang, as I figured I can manage the potential problems in a production environment . Anyways, thanks for the input, I guess I'll mark your post as the answer for my scenario.

Answer (score 0):

Also you can point desired version of python:

```
python3 manage.py ...
```

...or even:

```
/usr/bin/python3 manage.py ....
```